# Android Scrollview: " On scroll jump in fixed intervals"

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I desire to have a scroll effect in my android app that jumps in certain intervals on scroll.

For an example then what i want to achieve is when the user scrolls then it will scroll in intervals of 100dp in the direction the user scrolls.

Take a look at this picture: 
[image]

I have alot of Imageviews in a RelativeLayout which is inside a Scrollview. 
So what I want to achieve is when the user scrolls then one of the Imageviews will always be locked at the visual position once scrolling stops.

So is there a way to make a scrollview scroll at fixed rates?

Comment: Did you get your scroll function to work like you wanted? Which solution path did you use?

Comment: got it to work with a listview :) smoothScrollTo ended up in a sorry result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `void smoothScrollTo (int x, int y)` use the x,y position of the image you want to scroll to. Or use `void smoothScrollBy(int dx, int dy)` for set intervals.

Alternatively, you could use a `listView` and scroll with animation to a specific row